# Responsive Navigation Not Working

Tags: html, css, navigation, responsive-design

I have this navigation on this page: http://www.bkd.com/industries/private-equity/think-differently.htm

It is the navigation with the ExperienceBKD logo and the industries, services, thoughtware, client success and search bar.

The issue i am having once I added those links in the grey bar if you minimize the window or look at in on tablet/phone the navigation goes below the gray bar. I am needing it to stay responsive and stay in the format that you see when the screen is maximized.

The ASP file is called meg-menu4.asp if you need the coding from that I can supply it.

Here is the navigation CSS:

```
ul.meg-menu {
position: relative;
padding:0px;
margin: 0px;
float:left;
line-height:17px;
}
ul.meg-menu li.mgmu {
float:left;


}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov1, ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov2, ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov3, ul.meg-menu li.mgmu a.hov4 {
float:left;
padding: 25px 21px 10px 10px;

}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd {
display: none;
background:url(/images/common/mdd/mdd-bg.png) no-repeat bottom ;
left:-240px;
padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
position: absolute;
top: 77px;
width: 926px;

}

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd ul {
padding: 0px 10px 0px 0px;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd h4 {
padding-left: 0px;
line-height: normal;
margin-bottom:5px;
font-weight:bold;
color: #404040;

 }
ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd h4 a {
color: #404040;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd a {
color: #404040;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd .bd-right {
border-right: solid 1px #cccccc;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd .bd-bottom {
border-bottom: solid 1px #cccccc;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd .bd-top {
border-top: solid 1px #cccccc;

 }


ul.meg-menu li.mgmu div.meg-dd a:hover {
color: #b32017;
text-decoration:none;

 }

ul.meg-menu li.hovering div.meg-dd {
display: block;
}

ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov1, ul.meg-menu li a.hov1:hover { background:  url(/images/common/mdd/services-hover.png) top   center no-repeat;}
ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov2, ul.meg-menu li a.hov2:hover { background:  url(/images/common/mdd/industries-hover.png) top  center no-repeat;}
ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov3, ul.meg-menu li a.hov3:hover { background:  url(/images/common/mdd/thoughtware-hover.png) top  center no-repeat;}
ul.meg-menu li.hovering.mgmu a.hov4, ul.meg-menu li a.hov4:hover { background: url(/images/common/mdd/thoughtware-hover.png) top  center no-repeat;}

.mdd-video {font-size:11px; text-align:center;}
.mdd-video p {margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
```

What am I doing wrong or what am I missing? It works great on the page I built without the extra navigation in it (http://www.bkd.com/new-test-2.htm).

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I am not able to understand what you want to do exactly

Comment: Sorry. In the gray bar on that page. Where you see the ExperienceBKD logo.. After that is the words Services, Industries, Thoughtware, Client Success and then the search bar. If you move the window around the words and search bar go below the gray bar. I am needing them to stay there no matter what screen size. It also is there if you look at the page on the tablet. Sorry I was unclear. Have I explained better? http://www.bkd.com/industries/private-equity/think-differently.htm

Comment: I would like it to work more like the black navigation at the very top. NO matter what size it fits the spot.